# nodejs issue in starting on commandline

Tags: node.js

I am a newbie in node.js.I am getting a strange error in my code-
Failed to open socket on port 4243, waiting 1000 ms before retrying.

I tried using netstat -a but could not found opened port 4243.Kindly suggest the reason and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you did not tried to find its answer.

try ->

`pkill node*` in shell

and restart your app.

Let me know if you were able to get through it or not?